# How to fetch user's Youtube Playlist by YouTube API in android?

Tags: android, mobile, youtube, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any way for me to get user's playlist by AccountPicker?

Could somebody show me the exactly workflow?

I already read this https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:-**

First of all you need to create project in https://console.developers.google.com and get API key,
Check this [link](https://www.slickremix.com/docs/get-api-key-for-youtube/) for console registration process and how to get API key.it may help.

**After that follow this process**

1. **Get the channel id for the channel you want from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) (you probably only need to do this once, then you can save it)**

   Set **forUsername** to the name of the channel you want

   Grab the channel id (something like this: "id": "UCrX2VuXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
2. **Get the playlist from channel id you get in step 1:-**

   [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) you can check playlist by entering channel id which you get from step 1
3. **Get the videos via the playlistitems in the playlist using the playlist id from step 2**

   Go through each PlaylistItem and pull out the **videoId** and pass that **videoId** to Youtube player

**At last after this all process you have link like this as below.**

> And here is your final URL to get **PlayList**:-
>
> **https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId={ChannelID}&key={API
>   key} & maxResults=50**
>
> And to get **PlaylistItems**:
>
> **https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key= {API key} &maxResults=50 &playlistId = {id}**

Thats it. Let me know if you face any issue.

**UPDATE 1:-**

Check [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) link to get channel id from channel name

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key= {API key} &maxResults=50 &playlistId = {id}

this is not working..

Comment: @ArindamGhosh have done all these steps and obtained your **API Key** from [here](https://console.developers.google.com/)???

Comment: i follow this link [https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/android] to fetch Channel id.. but it gave the default channel id result "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw"... How do i fetch channel id ?

Comment: @ArindamGhosh hey..To get channel id use [THIS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list).

Comment: How do i get the Channel name..?? i am implementing  this is Android..i want User just login with your gmail account and fetch his/her channel id..

Comment: @ArindamGhosh ok than you have to use 3rd option  **list (my channel)** from **Use cases**

Comment: Thanks, Channel id fetch successfully...rest all process i'll do .. if i fetch any problem then i'll let you know.